# Word VBA: Case insensitive search

Tags: vba, search, ms-word, case-insensitive

I'm calling the Find dialog Box with `Dialogs(wdDialogEditFind).Show` but somehow by default the search is case sensitive. Can I turn it off in the macro code?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VBA, you can do something like

```vb
with Dialogs(wdDialogEditFind)
    .MatchCase = False
    .Show
end with
```